# Difference in seconds between two timestamps in Scala

Tags: scala, simpledateformat

So I have a timestamp in this format:

> 1990-10-31 18:43:12

I want to calculate the difference between two of these timestamps.

What I have attempted:

```
val t1 = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss")
val t2 = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss")
t1.parse(timestamp1)
t2.parse(timestamp2)
```

But what do I do after?

Comment: That's now a defunct answer, now java has `java.time`

Comment: I agree with @oxbow_lakes that you should prefer to go for a `java.time` solution. The linked question does provide a couple of `java.time` answers, just scroll down and find them.

Comment: Pure scala solution: `import scala.concurrent.duration._;
(t2 milliseconds) - (t1 milliseconds) < (12 hours)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Firstly, Java now has `java.time` (JDK 1.8 and later)

```
import java.time._
import java.time.format._
```

Then (note that formatters/parsers are now stateless, it's always safe to reuse them):

```
val p = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") //note months are MM

val t1 = LocalDateTime.parse(timestamp1, p)
val t2 = LocalDateTime.parse(timestamp2, p)
```

Now you have two date/times, you need to convert to instants (actually, `ZonedDateTime` but it's enough for your purposes):

```
val i1 = t1.atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/London"))
val i2 = t2.atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/London"))
```

Now you have two instants, you can diff them:

```
import java.time.temporal._
val diff = i1.until(i2, ChronoUnit.SECONDS) //Or MILLIS, MICROS etc
```

#### Appendix

Here is the REPL session:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

val timestamp1 = "1990-10-31 18:43:12"
val timestamp2 = "1991-09-29 18:43:12"

import java.time._
import java.time.format._

val p = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") 

val t1 = LocalDateTime.parse(timestamp1, p) 
val t2 = LocalDateTime.parse(timestamp2, p)

val i1 = t1.atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/London"))
val i2 = t2.atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/London"))

import java.time.temporal._
val diff = i1.until(i2, ChronoUnit.SECONDS)
```

And here are the results:

```
// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

timestamp1: String = 1990-10-31 18:43:12
timestamp2: String = 1991-09-29 18:43:12
import java.time._
import java.time.format._
p: java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter = Value(YearOfEra,4,19,EXCEEDS_PAD)'-'Value(MonthOfYear,2)'-'Value(DayOfMonth,2)' 'Value(HourOfDay,2)':'Value(MinuteOfHour,2)':'Value(SecondOfMinute,2)
t1: java.time.LocalDateTime = 1990-10-31T18:43:12
t2: java.time.LocalDateTime = 1991-09-29T18:43:12
i1: java.time.ZonedDateTime = 1990-10-31T18:43:12Z[Europe/London]
i2: java.time.ZonedDateTime = 1991-09-29T18:43:12+01:00[Europe/London]
import java.time.temporal._
diff: Long = 28767600
```

Comment: Good Answer but not quite right about the time zones. You can indeed calculate the span of time between two `LocalDateTime` objects. You should not arbitrarily apply any time zone. You should only apply the zone if you know for a fact that the data was intended to represent a moment in that zone but unfortunately omitted that zone info from the data itself. Tip: Always include the offset or zone info with your date-time strings, and use the standard ISO 8601 formats to do so, such as `2017-01-23T01:23:34.567Z` where the `Z` for Zulu means UTC.